# weird behavior of str_replace

Tags: php

I am trying to do a simple thing to change the slashes to back slashes in a file path. Windows 7 OS

```
<?php
$fileName = "C:\migration\files\gallery\2c1c7e72-781e-4347-ab39-6e77409b93d5.json";
echo $fileName."<br>";
echo str_replace ("\\","/", $fileName);
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
echo $fileContent; 
exit();
```

I run this code via Apache and command line and i see weird results

```
C:\migrationiles\galleryc1c7e72-781e-4347-ab39-6e77409b93d5.json
```

The second slash get disappear with letter f "\f" and fourth slash disappear with number 2 "/2" 
Can you guys explain me how it could be possible?

Comment: You haven't escaped the slashes in the `$fileName` variable

Comment: Well that's what's going on - [If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences for special characters: ...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Use single quotes. https://eval.in/835384 `str_replace` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you guys! Appreciate it.

Comment: Given an answer, I feel that there should be a community wiki answer given, from comments in this thread. IMHO anyway. Not my dv here btw.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening just because of escape sequencing charcters, you can't print `\` directly in php, to print `\` you should write it as `\\`. Use like this to replace the double backslashes from your string

```
$newstr = str_replace('\\\\', '/', $fileName);
```

or simply use regex for that as

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $fileName);
```

Comment: It's broken at the assignment of `$fileName` because of the double quotes.

Comment: I feel that the manual that CBroe [quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223196/weird-behavior-of-str-replace#comment77412638_45223196) from, is *the* explanation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah that is correct, there we get more explanation and examples

Comment: but what is \t, \2 mean. Why they got changed? I understand the concept of single quote and double quotes. what what wrong with \2

Comment: \t is horizontal tab, check the manual link provided by CBroe in the comment

Comment: and  \2 ? I knew what is \t but what is a second one

Comment: it may be taking as an octal or hexadecimal number

Comment: Yes, you are right it  means that str_replace use regex engine inside